# Calendar Button Entry

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus-formula

I have a button for Notes Calendar Entry.

Basically it just creates a new entry when some one clicks on it.

This is full Script:

```
Sub Click(Source As Button) 
    Dim s As New NotesSession
    Dim db As NotesDatabase
    Dim doc As NotesDocument
    Dim subject As String
    Dim maildoc As NotesDocument
    Dim rtitem As NotesRichTextItem
    Set db = s.CurrentDatabase
    Set doc = New NotesDocument(s.CurrentDatabase)
    Set maildoc = New NotesDocument(s.CurrentDatabase)
    Set ritem = New NotesRichTextItem(maildoc, "Body")

'Modify Subject, Location, Start Day and Time, End Day and Time before sending!!
'#########################################################################

    doc.subject = "HI"
    doc.location = "I2-300"
    Set startdatetime = New NotesDateTime("05/29/2014 04:00:00 PM")
    Set enddatetime = New NotesDateTime("05/29/2014 05:00:00 PM")
```

'#########################################################################

```
    doc.From = s.UserName
    doc.Form = "Appointment"
    doc.AppointmentType = "0"
    doc.Chair = s.UserName
    doc.StartDateTime = startdatetime.LSLocalTime
    doc.EndDateTime = enddatetime.LSLocalTime
    doc.CalendarDateTime = startdatetime.LSLocalTime
    doc.TimeRange = Timevalue(doc.startdatetime(0)) & "-" & Timevalue(doc.enddatetime(0))
    doc.ExcludefromView = "D"

    Call doc.ReplaceItemValue("_ViewIcon", 160)
    Call doc.AppendItemValue("$BusyName", s.UserName)
    Call doc.AppendItemValue("$BusyPriority", "1")
    Call doc.AppendItemValue("$PublicAccess", "1")
    Call doc.save(True,True)

    Print "An entry for this event was successfully added to your calendar and an e-mail confirmation was sent."
    Msgbox "Calendar successfully updated and e-mail confirmation sent.", 64, "Success"

    'Send e-mail confirmation

    maildoc.Form = "Memo"

'Modify Subject and Send to
'############################################################################   
    maildoc.Subject = "Yes - I will attend - May 29"
    maildoc.SendTo = "" 

'############################################################################
    Call maildoc.Send(False)

End Sub
```

Well My Question is How to add description field where can I insert the text and it should show up under description field In calendar entry.

Well I tried Doc.Description didn't work Entry is not getting Updated?

Can Some one take a look?

Answer (score 2):

Mail and calendar forms in Notes share many common fields.  One of those fields is called Body. In the Appointment form, the Body field is labeled "Description".  So Body is the one you want.

Body is a rich text field. You should use `doc.CreateRichTextItem("Body")` and the methods of the `NotesRichTextItem` class to work with it, instead of just using `doc.AppendItemValue("Body",someVariable)`.

In the future, please bear in mind that Notes developers can research many questions like this themselves very easily. Just open up the mail template in Domino Designer and look at the _CalendarEntry form. ("Appointment" is an alias.)  It's open source. You will see the fields there. Scroll all the way to the bottom and you will find the "Description" label, and below that you will see the Body field.  Many things in there are very messy, but the Body field isn't.  And for most other things you might be dealing with, it really is worth the time to study the messy bits to see how it works.